# “She got her first child” vs. “She had her first child”

Tags: word-choice, verbs, idioms

I am not a native speaker and yesterday someone told me that "She got her first child" would be misunderstood and "She had her first child" is correct. Now I wonder if this is a 'local' thing here in Wales or a general 'rule'.

Comment: It's not local.  "She had" is correct and "She got" is incorrect.

Comment: The standard idiom is _to have a baby_, where other nouns may be substituted for _baby_, like _boy, girl, child, heir_, but only ***have*** can be used. It refers to pregnancy (_she's having a baby_), the birth event (_She had her baby last week_), and subsequent family relations (_She has three boys and one girl_).

Comment: "She had" implies she gave birth.  To me at least, "she got" sounds like she adopted (or, y'know, went out and swiped a kid from somewhere, but people usually don't talk about doing that :-) ).

Answer (score 5):

“She got her first child” sounds like she got that child at some shop or via mail-order.  Just use *had* there: “She had her first child before she turned fourteen.”

Note also that “to get (someone) **with** child” has an old-timey kind of feel to it.
Shakespeare in *Measure for Measure* I.ii.66 refers to the punishment “for getting Madame Julietta with child”.

Comment: I agree.  I have heard a nonnative speaker wonder whether his wife would "get another baby".  In turn, I wondered where they would be going to pick one out.

Comment: @mikeY Presumably they would go to their local stork colony to pick out a new baby.

Comment: I think the phrase *"...for getting Madame Julietta with child"* refers to getting Madame Julietta *pregnant*, but the phrase *"Madame Julietta had a child"* would suggest she (successfully) gave birth.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Aye.